# вернуть рандомный текст из sql

Tags: android, sql

нужно вернуть рандомный текст  по клику из  name в sqlite, поставить в textview . Пошарил в инете, ничего не выходит. Подскажите плз как это прописать, после обращения к БД через курсор.Или может есть другой способ. Спасибо.

```
 case R.id.btn_text:
            Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
    // закрываем подключение к БД
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

Comment: А `order by random() limit 1` не подходит ? (первое что гугл выдает)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вбейте в гугл:

> [android cursor random](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20cursor%20random)

2. Перейдите по первой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8407284/3212712)
3. Скопируйте себе код:

   ```
   Cursor cursor = this.db.query("mytable Order BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
           new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null, null, null);
   ```
4. Запустите код.
5. Сравните ожидаемые результаты с полученными
6. В случае несовпадения - повторяйте п1-5, инкременируя порядковый номер ссылки из п.2

Comment: спасибо, проблема была в запуске через телефон, не знаю почему, через эмулятор пошло.

Answer (score 3):

То есть предполагается что у вас в таблице хранятся строковые имена, и надо достать одно из них с помощью рандома? Тогда будет примерный алгоритм:

1) Курсором пробегается и записываем все значения в `ArrayList<String>`
2) После чего вызываем у списка метод `.size()` чтобы узнать его длину
3) Если `size > 0`, то выполняем слудующее

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomValue = random.nextInt(size);
String name = list.get(randomValue + 1);
```

Таким образом всё должно получиться